# Triangular Images

Tags: html, css

I have two right triangle images that I want to put together like this (solid colors only for example):

[image]

I can think of a couple of ways to do this:

1. Divs with background images, and positioning them on top of each
   other
2. A similar approach to the above, but with images instead of divs

The problem comes from the fact that I want to be able to hover (and click) on each individual triangle and have it change it's state (such as change color on hover).

Both of my above solutions create the problem where one is on top of the other, and I cannot click or hover over the other. I was thinking of doing this with CSS shapes, but those usually involve borders and I don't know of a way to overlay the image on those.

I need to be able to accomplish this with just CSS and HTML, and ideally without an image map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

Edit: I didn't notice there was another answer with similar approach, had the answer window opened for awhile, sorry.

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.triangle:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.top_right {
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.top_right img{
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.bottom_left {
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
.bottom_left img{
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle top_right">
    <img src="http://www.avatarsdb.com/avatars/spongebob_happy.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="triangle bottom_left">
    <img src="http://www.avatarsdb.com/avatars/say_cheese.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually looks perfect. @sharf, if you haven't found a solution yet, give this one a try.

Comment: This works pretty well. Unfortunately I need it to be responsive...looks like i might be using some javascript...

Comment: It can surely be responsive. Just change the values to a responsive unit like vw or %

Comment: When setting the width and height to %, the images expand beyond the container. It could be my implementation though. I'll try again.

Comment: I'm unable to make it work in a responsive environment. The triangles move, but do not scale as the area (bootstrap columns) change sizes.

Comment: Alright I got it working, there were two changes I needed to make in order for it to be responsive: .triangle needed to be `position` relative, and then the bottom triangle absolute. Second, to make it work in IE, the images needed `pointer-events` none. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use css skew:

your html:

```
<div class="img-container">
   <img src="http://www.natureasia.com/common/img/splash/thailand.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="img-container">
   <img src="http://www.worddive.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/nature-and-environment-course.jpg"/>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.img-container, .img-container img { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.img-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  transform: skewX(-68deg);
}
.img-container:first-child {
  left: -.25em;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}
.img-container:last-child {
  right: -.25em;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
.img-container img {
  transform: skewX(68deg);
  transform-origin: inherit;
}
```

It will probably work better with square images, however you can play around with the `skew` until it looks right.

Check out this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v18ybdfj/3/) or rotating [the other way](https://jsfiddle.net/v18ybdfj/5/)

Again, not 100% sure on browser compatibility tho. If you need to guarantee that all browsers render properly you might be best of using images.

Comment: The solid colors are only for demonstration, they will be actual pictures. Updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: can you use javascript?

Comment: If it were possible to restrict border images to certain borders, you could use the `css-border` property. As it were, I can't for the life of me find a way to prevent it from applying the image to all four borders.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to make do with just CSS/HTML

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can make it work and get back to you.